# Iterate N numbers and do a sum on it using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a possible way to iterate N-numbers in LINQ to get a sum on it?

for instance:

```
var n = 3;

//The part I wonder about if you can do this entirely with LINQ
var t = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
    t += i;
}
```

Comment: Can always just use plain old maths: n(n-1)/2!

Comment: `int sum = n * (n - 1) / 2;` works perfectly fine @Sinatr

Comment: @Innat3, that .. really helps, thanks. ;) I even find the [proof](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/runsums/triNbProof.html) and totally missed the point of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate your list of numbers then [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734(v=vs.110).aspx) them

```
var n = 3;
var sum = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Sum();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a concise answer explaining Enumerable.Range. Didn't know it existed.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: If the 0 is not to be included, then the answer needs to be _"Enumerable.Range(1, n-1).Sum()"_

Answer (score 6):

```
int sum = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Sum();
```