# Calculate the sum of numbers from 1 to n using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
public static int Sum(int n)  { 
 ??
}
```

I don't know how to sum numbers from 1 to n using LINQ
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: The Range and Sum methods might be useful.

Comment: How high can `n` go? Do we have to consider scenarios could be a `long` rather than an `int`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate N numbers and do a sum on it using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768396/iterate-n-numbers-and-do-a-sum-on-it-using-linq)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var sum = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Sum();
```

---

However, you don't need to use Linq.  This formula returns the sum `1+2+..+n`:

```
var sum = n * (n+1) / 2;
```

These are known as the [Triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: how to use linq instead of var sum = n * (n+1) / 2; ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768642/how-to-use-self-defined-aggregate-function-with-linq