# How to use self defined aggregate function with LINQ? (without using extension methods)

Tags: c#, linq

In the question [Calculate the sum of numbers from 1 to n using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766937/calculate-the-sum-of-numbers-from-1-to-n-using-linq), the function sum was preexisting, what about when we want to define our own function ? for example SquareSum function, where the the square of numbers are to be added, or some other non preexisting function?

Edit : the use of extension method was commented, I was actually looking for a way to do it without extension methods.

Comment: Use extension methods https://www.dotnetperls.com/extension

Comment: @muddassir : can this extension method be defined on the derived class of sum extension method?

Comment: Could you show us what did you already try to solve this? So we can understand what is not working.

Comment: I agree with @MaximKosov Please show some code showing what you have tried.

Comment: @MaximKosov : what was not working was not knowing what is alternative way to creating extension methods, I did't know what is an alternative way of doing this, but thought somebody else might know, like the accepted answer of using anonymous method.

Comment: @earlyriser01 : what can be tried when one knows they dont want to use extension methods but dont know what can be tried? I could have written a for loop if I wanted to , but wanted to find the alternative way to extension method, what should I try if I dont know what it is the alternative that I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it like this

```
IEnumerable<int> range = Enumerable.Range(1, n);
var sum = range.Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x + y);
```

Sum of squares:

```
IEnumerable<int> range = Enumerable.Range(1, n);
var sum = range.Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x + y * y);
```

Comment: what about square sum? what would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below one.

If you have already an IEnumerable type which contains the numbers, you don't need any extension methods. You can directly use the Aggregate extention method like below.

```
num.Aggregate((a, b) => (a * a) + (b * b));
```

Edit: Folks, My apologies for the above wrong answer (`num.Aggregate((a, b) => (a * a) + (b * b));`). I just posted it without trying. One gentleman already posted the answer which is the correct one. However I find one more way for the same output

```
 num.Select(x => x * x).Sum();
```

Comment: was looking for a way without extension method

Comment: strange, why people are downvoting this, this is better answer than the one in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766937/calculate-the-sum-of-numbers-from-1-to-n-using-linq#60766979

Comment: @Arjang, my answer deserved that downvoting because I just posted blindly. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, just used your code for my project, much better than defining extension method to be used once.